# Why would a hangfire job run on more than one server?

Tags: hangfire, hangfire-sql

Why would our job run on multiple servers? We are using v 1.7.6 and the Job is launching on more than 1 server. Here is our configuration:

```
            services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
            .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
            .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
            .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
            .UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), new SqlServerStorageOptions
            {
                CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
                UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
                DisableGlobalLocks = true
            }));
```

From what I read, we are not supposed to use slidingexpiration any more in 1.7?

Comment: Are you sure the job is launched only one time?

Comment: You mean enqueued only 1 time? Yes.